# How do I update the duplicate values and their foreign key in the child table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables

```
Table A
Table B
```

Table A has 2 columns

```
ID, CellNo
```

Now Table B is the CHILD table of A.

In Table B, we have

```
ID, TableA_CellNO, TableA_ID.
```

I have duplicate CellNo's in table A and in Table B those two records exist but TableA_ID is updated with the wrong id's.

I need to Update all of the TableA_ID's with the correct values against the duplicate CellNo.

I have written a query to update by matching CellNo in both table but that doesn't work.

```
UPDATE TableA AS R 
   INNER JOIN TableB AS P 
       ON R.CellNo = P.TableA_CellNo 
SET P.TableA_ID = R.ID
```

Comment: If show us the query you have written to so solve it we may see what you did wrong.

Comment: Updated with code. check

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to update table A's Id to table B's *latest* Id, meaning that the last CellNo record inserted into B is the correct one.

This may not be the most efficient but it should work.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Id = b.Id
FROM TableA a
    JOIN TableB b
        ON b.Id = a.Id
           AND b.Id =
           (
               SELECT MAX(ib.Id) FROM TableB ib WHERE ib.CellNo = a.CellNo
           );
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. But this is not the case. I have duplicated entries in TABLEA with different IDs but in TableB the same entries (CellNo) are present with the same IDs. I want to update their IDs as per the TableA ids

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include a small data sample of table A and B?

Answer (score 0):

You 've a syntax error there. I suppose you 're looking for

```
UPDATE P
SET P.TableA_ID = R.ID
FROM TableA R 
JOIN TableB P ON R.CellNo = P.CellNo;
--WHERE <Some Conditions> if needed
```